# Umbrella Term for Multiplication and Division

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an umbrella term or name for both Multiplication and Division? Do these two operator types fall under one specific family with a particular name?

Comment: Let me clarify with an example to address the downvote. Regarding "Direction", we could say, North, South, East, and West are elements of Direction. The term, Direction is a superset of North, South, East, and West. When I inquire into the existence of a formal "Umbrella Term" in my original question, I relate this to inquiring into whether or not there's an "Umbrella Term" for North and South as a similar example (something that's a subset of Direction, but a Superset of North and South).

Comment: There seems to be something intuitive about the relationship between North and South, as there also seems to be a relationship between East and West, yet void of this relationship between North and East. So, my original question is an attempt to find a similar formal term or name for Multiplication and Division. I hope that makes sense. I did do a sufficient amount of research to attempt to answer this before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division can be rewritten as multiplication. Indeed, suppose that we want to evaluate $a:b$. Then, we can write this as $a \cdot b^{-1}$. Thus, division is multiplication, which is the "family" you were referring to. Here, $a,b$ are assumed to be, say, reals, with $b \neq 0$.